# Complexity of edge coloring graphs with $\Delta(G) \ge n/3$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Let $C$ be the class of graphs satisfying $\Delta(G) \ge n/3$, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of a graph $G$, and $n$ denotes the number of vertices.

1. What is the complexity of edge coloring graphs in $C$?
2. Is there a reduction from SAT to edge coloring graphs in $C$?

Related to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24927/the-overfull-conjecture-in-graph-theory-and-conp). A positive answer means a plausible graph theory conjecture implies $\sf NP=coNP$. A negative answer would greatly surprise me since all graphs of sufficiently large degree will be efficiently edge-colorable.

Possible approach is using some gadget like [here](http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/~hougardy/paper/girthall.pdf)

In addition this might help for counterexample for the conjecture (if false).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the other question, to contradict the conjecture (assuming $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{coNP}$) you need to show it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard to decide if the edge chromatic number of $G$ is at most $\Delta(G)$. This may not be the case but computing the edge chromatic number could still be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard (because say it's $\mathsf{NP}$-hard to decide if $3$ colors are enough).

Comment: To illustrate this kind of phenomenon, the gap closest vector problem in $n$-dimensional lattices is in $\mathsf{NP} \cap \mathsf{coNP}$ when the gap is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard when the gap is $n^{o(1)}$.

Comment: @SashoNikolov to contradict the conjecture is enough to show a counterexample, no matter if NP=coNP or not. If a SAT reduction exists, I suspect the reduction will give explicit counterexamples if NP \ne coNP.

Comment: Of course it's enough to give a counterexample. My point is that this sentence in the question is not strictly correct: "A positive answer means a plausible graph theory conjecture implies =." It doesn't, because a reduction showing edge coloring graphs in $C$ is NP-hard doesn't necessarily have to show it is NP-hard to decide of $\Delta$ colors are sufficient. This particular decision problem is not equivalent to the minimization problem.

Comment: @SashoNikolov What I meant was "reduction from SAT + conjecture imply NP=coNP". Reduction from SAT + conjecture gives short certificate for UNSAT when the CNF is UNSAT or am I missing something?

Comment: What you are missing (or I am not understanding you) is that a reduction to edge coloring graphs in $C$ is not sufficient for this. You need a reduction to deciding if the edge chromatic number of a graph $G$ in $C$ is at most $\Delta(G)$. This may be a much easier problem than edge coloring graphs in $C$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @SashoNikolov there is reduction from SAT to "Is 3-regular graph 3-EC". I am asking for reduction "SAT -> Is graph in C Class 1". As explained in the other question, the decision problem "is graph in C class 1", is NOT IN coNP since in both cases short certificates exist. Either Class 1 coloring (SAT instance of EC) xor existence of certain subgraph, which while hard is certainly not in coNP since the subgraph is certificate. Assuming the conjecture.

Comment: A problem can be in coNP and have short certificates for yes instances. What it is unlikely to be (unless NP = coNP) is coNP hard. All I am saying is that "is the graph $G$ in $C$ class 1" is a decision problem potentially much easier than the optimization problem of minimizing edge chromatic number of graphs in $C$. Which is why I find the wording of the question slightly problematic. I will let this be my last comment on the issue, I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346086/complexity-of-edge-coloring-graphs-with-deltag-ge-n-3-assuming-the-overful